# iOS delete form mutable array exception

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I am trying to delete something from my array but I getting exception

unrecognised selector
at delete

my code:

```
NSMutableArray* tempNewsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
tempNewsArray = [[defaults objectForKey:@"NewsArray"]mutableCopy];
for(int i = 0;i< [tempNewsArray count]-1;i++)
{
if( (monthIntofNew - month <= 10 && monthIntofNew - month !=0) || ( monthIntofNew - month <= -2))
    {
        [tempNewsArray delete:[tempNewsArray objectAtIndex:i]];//exception occurs here.
        //deleted
    }
}
```

I guess I am missing something, any help please?

Comment: It doesn't deal with the exception, but if you copy an array you do not need to allocate and initialize it

Comment: Didn't know it thanks for info :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delete:` is not any method name is `NSMutableArray`, you probably want to use `removeObject:` or `removeObjectAtIndex:`.

There are few other versions of remove as :

[image]

Comment: Thank you , and when do I use delete ?

Comment: yeah I see tyvm, is [code](delete) is actually the delete from C that frees the allocated memory ?

Comment: NO. `delete` is a keyword from C++. In C its parallel are malloc/calloc. The opposite of `delete` in C++ is `new`.

Answer (score 5):

Please try this,

```
int indexNum=-1;
NSMutableArray* tempNewsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
tempNewsArray = [[defaults objectForKey:@"NewsArray"]mutableCopy];
for(int i = 0;i< [tempNewsArray count]-1;i++)
{
if( (monthIntofNew - month <= 10 && monthIntofNew - month !=0) || ( monthIntofNew - month <= -2))
    {
       indexNum=i;
        //[tempNewsArray delete:[tempNewsArray objectAtIndex:i]];//exception occurs here.
        //deleted
    }
}

if(indexNum!=-1)
{
[tempNewsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexNum];
}
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: I see the key is [code](removeObjectAtIndex)
Thanks you :) helped

Answer (score 0):

The are two possible reason that I see for the exception (pls post the exception):

1. The one of anoop
2. If you remove object in an array that you are using for a loop/enumeration, you can easily go out of bounds of the array. Because the condition is based on a count that if delete an object is not valid anymore

Comment: If the function delete is actually the C function(that frees the allocated memory) then I see :)